# Django - Returning new form output in new line without overwriting previous output

Tags: python, html, django

I have been developing a bot using python and nltk and it works on the command line. Now I want to capture input using a web page, and I am transferring the logic to Django.
I will use a simpler example to demonstrate the problem I have.

In my index.html, I have a user entering a question into a single input box and upon clicking send, the view simply returns what they entered: their 'question' and 'answer' below the input box.
The problem is when they enter a new question it overwrites the previous one, but I would want the new question and answer to appear below the previous one as in a chat thread.

If maybe you do not get what I mean, I'll use images.

This happens:
[when the user enters first chat message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckYPV.png)
Then [when the user enters second chat message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EceQU.png)

What I want is this:
[to have both of them as a thread and not two overwriting one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGkOk.png)

I have just started using Django with this project and while with the cmd I could just use

```
while True:
```

I am a bit stumped on how to do it using the views and templates in Django.

Here's my index.html template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tedbot</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>Hello, I'm Tedbot</h1>
            <p>I'll help you join aBc University</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <strong>{{ boldmessage }}</strong>
        </div>
        <div>
            <form name='form' action="{% url 'index' %}" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="text" name="question"/>
                <input type="submit" name="send" value="send">
            </form>
        </div>

        <div>
            {{question}} <br />
            {{ answer }}
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

My forms.py

```
from django import forms

class ReturnAnswer(forms.Form):
    question = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And my views.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import nltk
import sklearn
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from tedbot.forms import ReturnAnswer

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    answer = "Something"
    question = "Something else"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        myform = ReturnAnswer(request.POST)

        if myform.is_valid():
            question = myform.cleaned_data['question']
            answer = myform.cleaned_data['question']
    else:
        myform = ReturnAnswer()
    #context_dict = {'boldmessage': "Sum messages"}
    return render(request, 'tedbot/index.html', {"answer": answer, "question":question})
```

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: I think, you can do this using javascript or jquery code which will append the newly element into existence html element.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store your questions and answers in database becouse when you click button you call a view which sends always last question and answer to template.

And then when your data is in database, you simply get all questions and answers and send it to template and show using {% for %}

Comment: Okay, but with my knowledge of Django, I would still pass the input the user gave as the {{question}} and the answer from the database as the {{answer}}. Would it then behave the way I want; as a thread

Comment: When you have stored your answers in database you can get all answers e.g. answers = Answer.objects.all(). And then you send to your tamplate variable called 'answers' which contains all answers.

Comment: And then in your template you can do this:

{% for answer in answers %}
  {{ answer }}
{% endfor %}

To show all answers